# VBA: Delete duplicate productid when it finds right criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba and if anyone can help me with a excel macro would I be grateful.

the macro shall:

Look for duplicate productid (Column T), when it finds duplicate productid so shall it keep the productid that have the lowest price (Column Q)
compared to the highest availability (Column O) and delete all the duplicate productid's that have highest and equal prices, compared with the highest availability.

There are also blank productid in column T that I want to keep and there are a header in the workbook and everything are in one workbook/sheet.

1. Look for duplicate productid.
2. Shall delete all duplicate productid with highest or equal prices that have the lowest availability.

Column T = Productid - Column Q = Price - Column O = Availability

I hope someone can help me with this macro.

Answer (score -1):

This is also posted on VBA Express